# Encoding CapturedRoomData with JSONEncoder

Tags: swift, codable, encodable, roomplan

I used to be able to encode [CapturedRoomData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/roomplan/capturedroomdata) to Data using JSONEncoder with the following code:

```swift
    // Encode CapturedRoomData
    func encodeCapturedRoomData(_ roomData: CapturedRoomData) -> Data? {
        print("#ECRD1 - Data: \(roomData)")
        do {
            let encodedRoom = try JSONEncoder().encode(roomData) // as Data
            print("#ECRD2 - Encoded: \(encodedRoom.description)")
            return encodedRoom
        } catch {
            print("#ECRD3 - Failed with error: \(error)")
        }
        return nil
    }
```

but a few weeks ago I noticed this approach is no longer working. The encoding fails and I get the following error:

> #ECRD3 - Failed with error: invalidValue(RoomPlan.CapturedRoomData, Swift.EncodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Invalid data", underlyingError: nil))

The roomData passed into the function in this example is the CapturedRoomData received from the [’didEndWith’](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/roomplan/roomcapturesessiondelegate/capturesession(_:didendwith:error:)-981ii) delegate method, running on a device with iOS 17.3.1.

**Edit:** Updating to the latest iPadOS (17.4.1) and Xcode (15.3) versions did not solve the problem

Can anyone help me find the root cause of this?

For reference, here’s what the CapturedRoomData looks like (with the keyframes omitted):

> #ECRD1 - Data: CapturedRoomData(keyframes: [...], coreAsset: <RSAsset: 0x283988bd0>, arFrameReferenceOriginTransform: simd_float4x4([[0.9995456, 0.0, 0.030147359, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-0.030147359, 0.0, 0.9995456, 0.0], [0.38664898, 0.93699455, 0.38685757, 1.0]]))

Comment: Your `encodeCapturedRoomData` seems fine. So it seems either that `roomData` isn't valid for some reason or there is a bug in iOS. Update your question showing how you get the value for `CapturedRoomData` that you pass to `encodeCaptureRoomData` and point out the version of iOS you are testing with.